# Tried to create a local server to broadcast data but got ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: python, websocket

Tried to create a local server to broadcast messages in python using the `websocket` module. (Mac OSX)

```
from websocket import create_connection

url = 'ws://localhost:8888/'

ws = create_connection(url)
ws.send("helloworld")
ws.close()
```

Saw this error: `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port 8888 is either closed or filtered. You most port forward it in your router.

Refer to this [guide](https://portforward.com).